# Accessing JWT Authorization token in Angular front-end - sent from back-end(spring) via response header

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I want to create a basic **login app** with Spring-boot back-end and Angular front-end.

Registered users are stored in the database. 
[image: user table in database]

Now, in the login page, user will enter email and password(not the encrypted one) in login URL: **/user/login**

If the user is registered in the database, back-end will send a JWT token along with the user id via response header (not via response body). See the code below in *successfulAuthentication* method:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        try {
            UserLoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), UserLoginRequestModel.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getEmail(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>()
                    )
            );

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String userName = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userName)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.getTokenSecret())
                .compact();

        UserService userService = (UserService) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("userServiceImpl");
        UserDto userDto = userService.getUser(userName);

        res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token); 
        // HEADER: Authorization: Bearer ...jsonwebtoken...

        res.addHeader("UserID", userDto.getUserId());
        // HEADER: UserId: asdf3232sf
    }
}
```

The backend works fine. See the Postman testing:
[image: POST req to login url with correct creds]

My question is: what is the Angular way of extracting those "Authorization" and "UserID" headers from the response header.

My final goal is to add those headers in browser storage and send with subsequent requests(for CRUD) from frontend to backend.

Please excuse my bad English.

Comment: You should return the token in the response

Comment: Better get `UserId`  from a claim in JWT token.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/users/login', {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'));
  console.log(response.headers.get('UserID'))
});
```